Does a Teaching Assistantship get counted as Teaching Experience when applying for teaching position in India?
In the Indian academic system, does one's teaching experience such as being a teaching assistant count towards one's application for an Assistant Professorship? My TAship involved everything from preparing class lectures, conducting long lectures, to maintaining grade lists. I have six years of experience of taking undergraduate classes as a TA. My question is whether I can put this as my teaching experience on application. Any leads on how to navigate this would be extremely helpful.

As far as I know and am aware of current considerations around hiring assistant professors (entry-level), the minimum criteria are these:

Must have a PhD or DPhil in a relevant discipline
Upper age limit (maybe 35 or 40; I am not sure!)
Teaching experience, if any (they are not too strict on this)

I believe I am fairly correct on this. Now, if you have pre-PhD experience, that will not be considered in most organisations. However, you can pose it as an additional and value-adding experience: preparing courses, handling students, examinations, etc. However, a TA-ship is not the same as a lectureship, which has much more than what a TA does. In this sense, TA experience might not be valued too much.
Additional note: You could also email the hiring committee before applying and possibly ask them for guidance on whether you should mention it as a relevant teaching experience or something else. Note also that it is always a good practice to clearly state in your resume/CV whether the experience was pre-, during- or Post-PhD. This also, however, varies between organisations.
Good luck!

TA experience can be mentioned in your teaching statement and CV, and this would make your application qualitatively stronger.
However, any pre-PhD teaching experience (or part-time experience gained during the PhD) does not typically count towards the formal teaching experience requirement for certain levels such as Associate Professor.
For. instance, if your application form asks for a numerical value for the number of years of teaching experience, what they're looking for is the number of years you've been employed as a faculty.
